# Need help figuring out what this Ember unloadAll does

Tags: ember.js, routes, ember-data

I have this route that currently, when I transition back to it, gives me this great big error with a stack trace that doesn't help me figure out what is going wrong.

> Error while processing route: project.details Assertion Failed: calling set on destroyed object Error: Assertion Failed: calling set
>   on destroyed object
>       at new Error (native)
>       at Error.EmberError (http://starqa.fmr.com/assets/vendor.js:22615:21)
>       at Object.Ember.default.assert (http://starqa.fmr.com/assets/vendor.js:15716:13)
>       at Object.set (http://starqa.fmr.com/assets/vendor.js:26367:22)
>       at exports.default.mixin.Mixin.create.set (http://starqa.fmr.com/assets/vendor.js:41034:20)
>       at Ember.Object.extend.flushCanonical (http://starqa.fmr.com/assets/vendor.js:69769:14)
>       at ember$data$lib$system$relationships$state$has_many$$ManyRelationship.flushCanonical
>   (http://starqa.fmr.com/assets/vendor.js:71525:22)
>       at Queue.invoke (http://starqa.fmr.com/assets/vendor.js:11425:18)
>       at Object.Queue.flush (http://starqa.fmr.com/assets/vendor.js:11490:13)
>       at Object.DeferredActionQue

Through just going through my routes and commenting out stuff, I found this in my **projects** route:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin, {
  model: function(params) {
    if (params.q) {
      return this.store.find('project', params);
    } else {
      var _this = this;
      Ember.run(function() {
        _this.store.unloadAll('project');
      });
      return this.store.findAll('project', {reload: true});
    }
  }
```

And if I comment out lines 7-9:

```
/*
  Ember.run(function() {
    _this.store.unloadAll('project');
  });
*/
```

then the error goes away and the transition worked. This bit of code was written by somebody else, and I *think* it has to do with refreshing the model from the store, but I can't figure out why it would cause this "calling set on a destroyed object" error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Offhand it looks like this route serves both single project param (q is specified) and all projects, which offhand sounds like far from perfect design for ember. Ideally you should have two routes - the projects and project route. That's on the Ember architecture side.

On the functional side, this happens when you object was released by ember yet you try and access it a second time. I suspect this is happening as the Ember.run, runs the unload all in another loop, whereas I don't think that's what's needed. Try to remove the unload all from the ember loop, or most chances you can just run without it at all (as why do you want to remove all the object in the current cache each time you call the route?

```
this.store.unloadAll('project');
return this.store.findAll('project', {reload: true});
```

Or just leave it commented out (I think leaving it commented should work for you).

Comment: There was something about it not pulling stuff back from the store, hence the unload/reload.  To your other point, I do have a singular `project` route, but this projects route returns a default list of projects, and on that page is a search box, which sets the query, which returns a different list of projects from the API that match the query, so it's still multiple projects.

Comment: Also taking out the Ember.run() wrapper results in the same error.

Comment: I'm not sure, what does it mean something about it not pulling stuff back from the store? why would you want to unload and reload each time you hit the route? it makes no sense, really..

Comment: My memory is apparently short: [my own question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31886063/clear-data-from-embers-store-before-doing-findall) is why I needed to do this in the first place.

Comment: well that sounds very weird, what I would suggest you do is never clear all the local storage and reload, but derive another route (top level) / have a background service that runs once in a while and trims out old records, unloading and reloading seems like a very bad design..IMO

Comment: I'm sure you're right, but I honestly have no clue how to implement what you suggest. This loading/unloading is just one step down from my application route and seems to already be in the appropriate place. At the same time, this querying and then going back doesn't seem to be too crazy of a use case, so there's got to be a better way to do it, but it took me forever just to figure out the loading/unloading in the first place.